# Does an observer on an expanding three-sphere naturally have a hyperbolic sense of time?

Tags: metric-spaces, semi-riemannian-geometry

On can consider the 3-sphere of radius a
  as being embedded in a four-dimensional Euclidean space. One has in this view the condition for any coordinate system with origin at the center of the 3-sphere:

$$a^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}x^{\mu}x^{\nu}$$

Note that the metric here is Riemannian (not pseudoriemannian). In standard Cartesian coordinates for example this reads:

$$a^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+w^{2}$$

This is simply the condition that the coordinates lie somewhere on the 3-sphere. For a 3-sphere of changing radius a
 , one can write this infinitesimally as:

$$da^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$$

Where it is clear that a
  will be a function of some external parameter (time or conformal time). Let us now allow a body to move around on the three-sphere while it is expanding. For a coordinate choice with three variables (\chi
 ) on the three sphere, one has an infinitesimal displacement given by:

$$dl^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}\frac{d\chi^{\mu}}{dt}dt\frac{d\chi^{\nu}}{dt}dt$$

Our total displacement condition then becomes:

$$dL(t,\dot{\chi})^{2}=da(t)^{2}+g_{\mu\nu}d\chi(t)^{\mu}d\chi(t)^{\nu}$$

But $L$
  is not invariant; different observers would argue over the value of $L$
 . $a$
  is however is invariant, being agreed upon regardless of position on the three sphere. In this manner it is somewhat more natural to rewrite:

$$-da(t)^{2}=-dL^{2}+g_{\mu\nu}d\chi(t)^{\mu}d\chi(t)^{\nu}$$

It makes sense here to designate $L=\chi^{0}$
  and a pseudoriemannian metric such that:

$$-da(t)^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}d\chi^{\mu}d\chi^{\nu}$$

Note this argument also applies for two arbitrary points on $S^{3}$
 at two differing values of $a$
 . Given the different geometric roles of a
  and L
  (as compared to dimensions on $S^{3}$
 ), one might choose different units such that $a=c\tau$
  and $\chi^{0}=ct$
  where c
  is a constant. Note one then has the natural condition:

$$-c^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}\frac{d\chi^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{d\chi^{\nu}}{d\tau}$$
Locally, for large a, this looks a lot like the conditions of Lorentz invariance as in Special relativity.